# Custom ToggleButton findViewById Null Pointer

Tags: view, nullpointerexception, togglebutton

I have been trying to solve this problem for hours now and have exhausted all the obvious solutions.  I have a custom toggle button that works fine as long as I don't try to get it using findViewById

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class WeekButton extends ToggleButton {

    private static int mWidth;

    public WeekButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public WeekButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is the layout..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <org.myname.projetname.reminders.WeekButton.WeekButton
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mondayToggleButton"
        style="@style/RecurrenceDayOfWeekStyle"
        android:textOff="  Mon"
        android:textOn="  Mon" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Exception occurs here..

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_reminder_activity);
        //This causes null pointer
        WeekButton weekButton = (WeekButton)findViewById(R.id.mondayToggleButton));
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

SOLUTION: Turns out I forgot to instantiate the list I was adding the WeekButtons which made it look like the call to find id was working but it was.  Thank you everyone you tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't it show any error before run? xml name space attribute is given for the parent tag.

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

<org.myname.projetname.reminders.WeekButton.WeekButton
    android:id="@+id/mondayToggleButton"
    style="@style/RecurrenceDayOfWeekStyle"
    android:textOff="  Mon"
    android:textOn="  Mon" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, Cast to your class on `findViewById()`.

Comment: That's where I had it originally but I saw a couple posts saying adding it to the custom view fixed the problem. Sadly neither work for me.

Comment: As I mentioned below the cast was there just missed in when typing it into the post.  Still having the problem, thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to instantiate a list I was adding the weekbuttons to.